# Is it OK for SEO for a blog post to link to an ecommerce product page and vice versa?

Tags: seo, web-development, links, blog

I am referring to an e-commerce environment, there is the blog part and the website part. I know that the blog should link to the product page, but is it a wise choice to link a product page back to one/or more other blog posts?

Lets say I sell clothes on my website and have recently launched a new t-shirt. I have a blog post that announces my new arrivals, with a link in the post going to this new t-shirt. On this t-shirt product page I have details regarding the t-shirt, like colour, size, type of material, type of stitch, etc.

Lets say a person is interested in the t-shirt and sees that the t-shirt is made of nylon and doesn't know what nylon is and would like to know more about nylon. So I was thinking of making the nylon text a link, when the user clicks on the nylon link, the user is able to read up more on nylon. Or lets say the t-shirt was stitched in a certain way, and the user wants to know more about this type of stitch, then a link takes the user to a page with more information on the type of stitch.

Now I have a question, should these information links link back to a blog post that was written about nylon or the type of stitch? Or should something more simpler be used like linking to a glossary page? My actual question is, if a blog post links to a product page, is it OK to link back from that product page to another blog post/blog posts?

Comment: It sounds like the links would be useful to users.  As far as "is it OK" that is usually the standard by which Google would not penalize your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an seo perspective it's perfect ally ok even good, last weeks google webmasters hangout was telling us that cross linking is becoming increasingly more important, from a conversion point of view I would be very carful about driving traffic off a purchase page, perhaps a glossary in a lightbox could be a good alternative.